Anomaly detection by PCA
I have a project about detecting anomalies using the PCA algorithm, and I have coded the algorithm yet. However, I struggle with how to identify anomalies. Do you recommend some documents or explain the suitable algorithm to deal with it?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
